# Facebook Lead Ad - Continued Flow : not passing data as hash parameters

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I created a FB lead ad following the steps mentioned [here](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/397336587121938). I provided the "**Destination url**" as mentioned in step 7. I have also enabled my page(Destination url) to read hash parameters for continued flow as mentioned at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/v2.5#continuedflow. But when lead ad form is submitted, no data is being passed as hash parameters.
If anyone have successfully used this feature or know how to make it work, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you whitelisted for the product?

Comment: Hi Paul Bain, how is possible to be whitelisted?

Answer (score 0):

I'm whitelisted and this is what I found already

- GET leads send answers on the hash (why not in the query string?? WHY???) (*)
- POST leads send answers in the body (as expected)

Since I need to process this on the server side, I'm redirecting the GET requests with parameters in the hash to GET requests with parameters in the query string.

(*) not all leads bring the data in the hash, sometimes the hash is empty, I'm currently debugging this.

Comment: @Chofoteddy well, you need to spend a lot of money and/or be in one of their tech acceleration programs. Apply to FbStart.com , it's pretty cool